# Using strtok() in nested loops in C?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am trying to use `strtok()` in nested loops but this is not giving me desired results,
possibly because they are using the same memory location. My code is of the form:-

```
char *token1 = strtok(Str1, "%");
while (token1 != NULL)
{
    char *token2 = strtok(Str2, "%");
    while (token2 != NULL)
    {
        //Do something
        token2 = strtok(NULL, "%");
    }
    // Do something more
    token1 = strtok(NULL, "%");
}
```

Comment: So, now you know why people don't use `strtok()` if they can avoid it.  It is hard to use correctly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, `strtok()`, indeed, uses some static memory to save its context between invocations. Use a reentrant version of `strtok()`, `strtok_r()` instead, or `strtok_s()` if you are using VS (identical to `strtok_r()`).

It has an additional context argument, and you can use different contexts in different loops.

```
char *tok, *saved;
for (tok = strtok_r(str, "%", &saved); tok; tok = strtok_r(NULL, "%", &saved))
{
    /* Do something with "tok" */
}
```

Comment: In case you don't edit in the reason why `strtok` is behaving this way, here's some more information about `strtok_r`: http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok_r.3.asp

Comment: Could someone please explain how the above loop works?

Comment: @MortalMan: that loop on its own can use `strtok()` or `strtok_r()` (or Microsoft `strtok_s()`) with minimal changes for the different calling convention of `strtok()`.  It simply steps through the tokens in `str`.  What's different about using `strtok_r()` is that you could have an inner loop also using `strtok_r()` and a different variable in place of `saved` and the inner loop would not interfere with the outer loop.  That _cannot_ be done with `strtok()`.

Answer (score 2):

strtok is using a static buffer.
In your case you should use strtok_r. This function is using a buffer provided by the user.

Answer (score 1):

WayneAKing posted [an alternative](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/39d70499-4a7a-47af-add1-806951d4513d) in the Microsoft Developer Center.

Citing him:

> Go here
>
> [http://cpp.snippets.org/code/](https://web.archive.org/web/20110305051412/http://cpp.snippets.org/code/)
>
> and download this file
>
> `stptok.c`     Improved tokenizing
>   function
>
> You can also download the needed
>   header files from the same site.
>
> This is a modified version of strtok
>   which places the parsed tokens
>   (substrings) in a separate buffer. You
>   should be able to modify it to
>   accommodate your needs.
>
> - Wayne
>
> P.S. - Note that these files may be in
>   *nix format with respect to end-of-lines. i.e. - 0x0A only and not
>   0x0D 0x0A

This is an alternative if you don't have the Microsoft libraries in your environment.