# What are the differences between strtok and strsep in C

Tags: c, strtok, strsep

Could someone explain me what differences there are between `strtok()` and `strsep()`?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of them?
And why would I pick one over the other one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From The GNU C Library manual - [Finding Tokens in a String](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html):

> One difference between `strsep` and `strtok_r` is that if the input string contains more than one character from delimiter in a row `strsep` returns an empty string for each pair of characters from delimiter. This means that a program normally should test for `strsep` returning an empty string before processing it.

Comment: can u give me an example please I am a bit confused

Comment: You can find examples of using these functions if you click on [link](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html) :-) Also please note that `strsep` function may be absent in your C compiler.

Answer (score 69):

One major difference between [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) and [`strsep()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?strsep(3)) is that `strtok()` is standardized (by the C standard, and hence also by POSIX) but [`strsep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) is not standardized (by C or POSIX; it is available in the GNU C Library, and originated on BSD).  Thus, portable code is more likely to use `strtok()` than `strsep()`.

Another difference is that calls to the `strsep()` function on different strings can be interleaved, whereas you cannot do that with `strtok()` (though you can with `strtok_r()`).  So, using `strsep()` in a library doesn't break other code accidentally, whereas using `strtok()` in a library function must be documented because other code using `strtok()` at the same time cannot call the library function.

The manual page for `strsep()` at [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strsep.3.html) says:

> The strsep() function was introduced as a replacement for strtok(3), since the latter cannot handle empty fields.

Thus, the other major difference is the one highlighted by [George Gaál](https://stackoverflow.com/users/698689/george-gaal) in his answer; `strtok()` permits multiple delimiters between a single token, whereas `strsep()` expects a single delimiter between tokens, and interprets adjacent delimiters as an empty token.

Both `strsep()` and `strtok()` modify their input strings and neither lets you identify which delimiter character marked the end of the token (because both write a NUL `'\0'` over the separator after the end of the token).

#### When to use them?

- You would use `strsep()` when you want empty tokens rather than allowing multiple delimiters between tokens, and when you don't mind about portability.
- You would use `strtok_r()` when you want to allow multiple delimiters between tokens and you don't want empty tokens (and POSIX is sufficiently portable for you).
- You would only use `strtok()` when someone threatens your life if you don't do so.  And you'd only use it for long enough to get you out of the life-threatening situation; you would then abandon all use of it once more.  It is poisonous; do not use it.  It would be better to write your own `strtok_r()` or `strsep()` than to use `strtok()`.

#### Why is `strtok()` poisonous?

The `strtok()` function is poisonous if used in a library function.  If your library function uses `strtok()`, it must be documented clearly.

That's because:

1. If any calling function is using `strtok()` and calls your function that also uses `strtok()`, you break the calling function.
2. If your function calls any function that calls `strtok()`, that will break your function's use of `strtok()`.
3. If your program is multithreaded, at most one thread can be using `strtok()` at any given time — across a sequence of `strtok()` calls.

The root of this problem is the saved state between calls that allows `strtok()` to continue where it left off.  There is no sensible way to fix the problem other than "do not use `strtok()`".

- You can use `strsep()` if it is available.
- You can use POSIX's [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) if it is available.
- You can use Microsoft's [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) if it is available.
- Nominally, you could use the ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Annex K.3.7.3.1 function `strtok_s()`, but its interface is different from both `strtok_r()` and Microsoft's `strtok_s()`.

BSD `strsep()`:

```
char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
```

POSIX `strtok_r()`:

```
char *strtok_r(char *restrict s, const char *restrict sep, char **restrict state);
```

Microsoft `strtok_s()`:

```
char *strtok_s(char *strToken, const char *strDelimit, char **context);
```

Annex K `strtok_s()`:

```
char *strtok_s(char * restrict s1, rsize_t * restrict s1max,
               const char * restrict s2, char ** restrict ptr);
```

Note that this has 4 arguments, not 3 as in the other two variants on `strtok()`.

Comment: Note that the Annex K `strtok_s()` is declared as: `char *strtok_s(char * restrict s1,
rsize_t * restrict s1max,
const char * restrict s2,
char ** restrict ptr);` which doesn't match the interface of Microsoft's `strtok_s()` or POSIX's `strtok_r()`.  Even if it was implemented, the difference is annoying — it limits the usefulness of the Annex K function. See also [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions)

Comment: I got very little actual information from your highly rated explanation. I say this only because it seems like you believe your explanation may be rather exhaustive and may make the whole matter quite clear and it probably does to high intelligence people, but it was almost entirely opaque to me. It doesn't really answer the question for me at all. I had to look up the term interleave (alternate layers). So no multithreading I guess.  "multiple delimiters between a single token" By 'token' you mean a substring? But every call creates a substring when it writes a '\0'. I am totally confused.

Comment: I'm sorry that you got no information out of my answer, @iamoumuamua.  The specification of [`strtok()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8) says: _A sequence of calls to the `strtok` function breaks the string pointed to by `s1` into a sequence of tokens, each of which is delimited by a character from the string pointed to by `s2`._  So, tokens are what `strtok()` identifies.  _[…continued 1…]_

Comment: _[…continuation 1…]_ The statement "calls to the `strsep()` function on different strings can be interleaved, whereas you cannot do that with `strtok()`" means that you can use `strsep()` to slice and dice two different strings in parallel, taking first a token from `string1` then a token from `string2`, whereas `strtok()` requires you to completely split `string1` before you tackle `string2` or vice versa.  Yes, that means no multi-threading with `strtok()`, but it also severely constrains single-threaded programs too.  _[…continued 2…]_

Comment: _[…continuation 2…]_ The tokens found by `strtok()` and `strsep()` are separated by delimiters.  With `strtok()`, multiple adjacent delimiters are treated as part of a single gap between tokens (so you cannot have empty tokens with `strtok()`), whereas `strsep()` assumes each token is separated from the next by a single delimiter, and two adjacent delimiters mean there is an empty token between them.

Comment: Those are exactly the sort of sentences I have difficulty parsing. I think I just need to see some concrete examples or a 'for dummies' explanation. Actually I think I understand the multiple delimiter thing now. Thanks. I use strtok() for transforming a block of memory (buffer) after reading a text file into what I think of as a multistring which is a block of memory with contiguous null terminated strings. For me the problem is I cannot get the address of the last substring if there is no delimiter like " " at the end. Trying to figure out if strsep() or strtok_r() may be better but...

Comment: @iamoumuamua — `strtok()` identifies tokens which are separated by delimiters.  Any character that is not a delimiter is part of a token.  When called, `strtok()` skips over any leading delimiters, then identifies the first non-delimiter and records its position, which it will return.  It skips over one or more non-delimiters which make up the token.  When it encounters a delimiter, or reaches the end of the string (a null byte, `'\0'`), it ensures that the token is null terminated. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continued…]_  It records where it got to in a private variable (which is what causes most of the problems with `strtok()`), and returns the pointer to the start of the token it just found.  When it is next called with a `NULL` pointer as the first argument, it retrieves where it got to from the private variable, and resumes its scanning, skipping over any delimiters before finding a non-delimiter, and so on.  The sets of delimiter characters can be different for different calls to `strtok()`, even when operating on a single string.  _[…continued again…]_

Comment: _[…next continuation…]_  The `strtok_r()`, `strtok_s()` and `strsep()` functions all avoid the private variable; the user passes storage space to the function for that information.  This means that they are thread-safe and reentrant and can be used to analyze different strings in parallel.

Comment: @iamoumuamua — you said "I cannot get the address of the last substring if there is no delimiter … at the end".  You get the last token by repeatedly calling `strtok()`, first with a pointer to the start of the string to be analyzed, and thereafter with `NULL` (as the first argument).  You get a new token on each call until there are no tokens left, whereupon `strtok()` returns a `NULL` pointer, indicating that there are no more tokens left.  You won't know you've read the last token until you try to read the (non-existent) token after the last one.

Comment: That clarified things a lot for me. As I said I use strtok() to sort of divide up a text file buffer into lines and then into words per line and store the pointers to these substrings in arrays. The array of lines is no problem because I can put a '\n' at the end, but for the words in a line if the last word  does not have a space at the end I don't think strtok(NULL," ") returns the address of that last word. I am thinking I need one last call to strtok(NULL,"\n") maybe.

Comment: @iamoumuamua — You may find [Nested `strtok` function problem in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4693884/15168) or [Using `strtok()` in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1509654/15168) informative.  Your description of splitting a buffer into lines at newlines `'\n'` and then into words (probably based on white space) is very like the scenarios in those questions.  The answers make it clear that `strtok()` is not a good tool to use for such problems — but that `strtok_r()`, `strtok_s()` and `strsep()` are all reasonable tools to use (though `strsep()` has different semantics from the others).

Comment: for `strsep` for windows, see [Is there a Windows variant of strsep() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512958/is-there-a-windows-variant-of-strsep-function)

Answer (score 9):

First difference in `strtok()` and `strsep()` is the way they handle contiguous delimiter characters in the input string.

Contiguous delimiter characters handling by `strtok()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char* teststr = "aaa-bbb --ccc-ddd"; //Contiguous delimiters between bbb and ccc sub-string
    const char* delims = " -";  // delimiters - space and hyphen character
    char* token;
    char* ptr = strdup(teststr);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "strdup failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("Original String: %s\n", ptr);

    token = strtok (ptr, delims);
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok (NULL, delims);
    }

    printf ("Original String: %s\n", ptr);
    free (ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./example1_strtok
Original String: aaa-bbb --ccc-ddd
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
Original String: aaa
```

In the output, you can see the token `"bbb"` and `"ccc"` one after another. `strtok()` **does not indicate the occurrence of contiguous delimiter characters**. Also, the `strtok()` **modify the input string**.

Contiguous delimiter characters handling by `strsep()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    const char* teststr = "aaa-bbb --ccc-ddd"; //Contiguous delimiters between bbb and ccc sub-string
    const char* delims = " -";  // delimiters - space and hyphen character
    char* token;
    char* ptr1;
    char* ptr = strdup(teststr);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "strdup failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptr1 = ptr;

    printf ("Original String: %s\n", ptr);
    while ((token = strsep(&ptr1, delims)) != NULL) {
        if (*token == '\0') {
            token = "<empty>";
        }
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }

    if (ptr1 == NULL) // This is just to show that the strsep() modifies the pointer passed to it
        printf ("ptr1 is NULL\n");
    printf ("Original String: %s\n", ptr);
    free (ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./example1_strsep
Original String: aaa-bbb --ccc-ddd
aaa
bbb
<empty>             <==============
<empty>             <==============
ccc
ddd
ptr1 is NULL
Original String: aaa
```

In the output, you can see the two empty string (indicated through `<empty>`) between `bbb` and `ccc`. Those two empty strings are for `"--"` between `"bbb"` and `"ccc"`. When `strsep()` found a delimiter character `' '` after `"bbb"`, it replaced delimiter character with `'\0'` character and returned `"bbb"`. After this, `strsep()` found another delimiter character `'-'`. Then it replaced delimiter character with `'\0'` character and returned the empty string. Same is for the next delimiter character.

**Contiguous delimiter characters are indicated when `strsep()` returns a pointer to a null character** (that is, a character with the value `'\0'`).

The `strsep()` **modify the input string as well as the pointer** whose address passed as first argument to `strsep()`.

Second difference is, `strtok()` relies on a static variable to keep track of the current parse location within a string. This implementation requires to **completely parse one string before beginning a second string**. But this is not the case with `strsep()`.

Calling `strtok()` when another `strtok()` is not finished:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void another_function_callng_strtok(void)
{
    char str[] ="ttt -vvvv";
    char* delims = " -";
    char* token;

    printf ("Original String: %s\n", str);
    token = strtok (str, delims);
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf ("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok (NULL, delims);
    }
    printf ("another_function_callng_strtok: I am done.\n");
}

void function_callng_strtok ()
{
    char str[] ="aaa --bbb-ccc";
    char* delims = " -";
    char* token;

    printf ("Original String: %s\n", str);
    token = strtok (str, delims);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",token);
        another_function_callng_strtok();
        token = strtok (NULL, delims);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    function_callng_strtok();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./example2_strtok
Original String: aaa --bbb-ccc
aaa
Original String: ttt -vvvv
ttt
vvvv
another_function_callng_strtok: I am done.
```

The function `function_callng_strtok()` only print token `"aaa"` and does not print the rest of the tokens of input string because it calls `another_function_callng_strtok()` which in turn call `strtok()` and it set the static pointer of `strtok()` to `NULL` when it finishes with extracting all the tokens. The control comes back to `function_callng_strtok()` `while` loop, `strtok()` returns `NULL` due to the static pointer pointing to `NULL` and which make the loop condition `false` and loop exits.

Calling `strsep()` when another `strsep()` is not finished:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void another_function_callng_strsep(void)
{
    char str[] ="ttt -vvvv";
    const char* delims = " -";
    char* token;
    char* ptr = str;

    printf ("Original String: %s\n", str);
    while ((token = strsep(&ptr, delims)) != NULL) {
        if (*token == '\0') {
            token = "<empty>";
        }
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }
    printf ("another_function_callng_strsep: I am done.\n");
}

void function_callng_strsep ()
{
    char str[] ="aaa --bbb-ccc";
    const char* delims = " -";
    char* token;
    char* ptr = str;

    printf ("Original String: %s\n", str);
    while ((token = strsep(&ptr, delims)) != NULL) {
        if (*token == '\0') {
            token = "<empty>";
        }
        printf("%s\n", token);
        another_function_callng_strsep();
    }
}

int main(void) {
    function_callng_strsep();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./example2_strsep
Original String: aaa --bbb-ccc
aaa
Original String: ttt -vvvv
ttt
<empty>
vvvv
another_function_callng_strsep: I am done.
<empty>
Original String: ttt -vvvv
ttt
<empty>
vvvv
another_function_callng_strsep: I am done.
<empty>
Original String: ttt -vvvv
ttt
<empty>
vvvv
another_function_callng_strsep: I am done.
bbb
Original String: ttt -vvvv
ttt
<empty>
vvvv
another_function_callng_strsep: I am done.
ccc
Original String: ttt -vvvv
ttt
<empty>
vvvv
another_function_callng_strsep: I am done.
```

Here you can see, calling `strsep()` before completely parse one string doesn't makes any difference.

So, the disadvantage of `strtok()` and `strsep()` is that both modify the input string but `strsep()` has couple of advantages over `strtok()` as illustrated above.

From [**strsep**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strsep/):

> The strsep() function is intended as a replacement for the strtok() function.  While the strtok() function should be preferred for portability reasons (it conforms to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (``ISO C90'')) it is unable to handle empty fields, i.e., detect fields delimited by two adjacent delimiter characters, or to be used for more than a single string at a time. The strsep() function first appeared in 4.4BSD.

---

For reference:

- [strtok() and strtok_r()](https://www.linuxsecrets.com/man-html/htmlman3/strtok.3.html)
- [strsep()](https://www.linuxsecrets.com/man-html/htmlman3/strsep.3.html)

Comment: Hi. Reference links seems invalid. can you change to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html or other valid link..