# Is there a Windows variant of strsep() function?

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to parse a delimited string that has some *empty* parameters.

Example:

```
"|One|two|three||octopus|garbagecan||cartwheel||||"
```

Basically I need to be able to pull out any segment by id, and if the segment is empty return `null`.

`strtok()` doesn't handle the empty fields, and it looks like there is `strsep()` for *nix based systems.  Anyone know if there is something similar for Windows? I want to try and avoid having to write a function to handle this if I can.

Comment: Maybe you can use this one ? http://www.mail-archive.com/busybox@busybox.net/msg11257.html

Comment: Why don't you just use `strsep` itself. If it isn't on your tools, get it from a BSD distro.

Comment: @David Heffernan - Easier said than done for this install.  Enterprise software that has it's own custom toolset, includes, code library, etc...  I cannot just toss in arbitrary .c/.h files and have them compile.  Everything has to be defined and built via their toolset.  Once the functions are designed in their tool set I can write my own C.  I might be able to scrap out the `C`, create my own function from it and retain the license, but it wouldn't be a copy of the BSD version (and I think that violates the license?).  It looks like the BSD needs `config.h` as well which would be a no-go...

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you have to solve this without being able to add code?

Comment: @david Heffernan - I can add code, but it has to be to predefined .c & .h files (me adding a function).  I cannot add an arbitrary .c/.h to the system and use it with a `#include`.  It also gets a little tricky because the system uses Unicode so I would have to change the BSD .c file to accommodate that as well.  I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur: you are making it more complicated than it is. `strsep` is just a `char` manipulation routine that does not depend on anything else; you can grab it from e.g. [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch#E_EmiR_o2X8/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-3.7.1p1.tar.gz|zmUSqAaGiDw/openssh-3.7.1p1/openbsd-compat/strsep.c&q=strsep&type=cs) (OpenSSH) and add it to your code (remember to comply to the terms of the BSD license).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just write the function using its description, it's not terribly complex:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* mystrsep(char** stringp, const char* delim)
{
  char* start = *stringp;
  char* p;

  p = (start != NULL) ? strpbrk(start, delim) : NULL;

  if (p == NULL)
  {
    *stringp = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    *p = '\0';
    *stringp = p + 1;
  }

  return start;
}

// Test adapted from http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html.

int main(void)
{
  char string[] = "words separated by spaces -- and, punctuation!";
  const char delimiters[] = " .,;:!-";
  char* running;
  char* token;

#define PRINT_TOKEN() \
  printf("token: [%s]\n", (token != NULL) ? token : "NULL")

  running = string;
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "words" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "separated" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "by" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "spaces" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "and" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "punctuation" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => "" */
  PRINT_TOKEN();
  token = mystrsep(&running, delimiters); /* token => NULL */
  PRINT_TOKEN();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this will be helpful.  Ive never seen the `if` statements with the `#` preceding them before, what is that for?

Comment: Ouch. #if is a preprocessing directive. Read something up on them, [a Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), for example.

Comment: :) yeah its been a long time since Ive done `c` work, you can see there is a little bit of rust.

Comment: I've simplified it. It needed a NULL-pointer check for `strpbrk()`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a public-domain `strsep()` implementation located at http://unixpapa.com/incnote/string.html that I've used before. It requires `strcspn()` though, a C90 function that you might not have.

Comment: please copy the 12 lines of code

Answer (score 2):

Gnu have a port of some of the [glibc functions to windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libgw32c.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`strsep` for windows from http://unixpapa.com/incnote/string.html

```c
// strsep for windows. by Dan Cross. requires strcspn
// https://unixpapa.com/incnote/string.html
#ifndef STRSEP_H
#define STRSEP_H
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
char *strsep(char **sp, char *sep) {
    char *p, *s;
    if (sp == NULL || *sp == NULL || **sp == '\0') return NULL;
    s = *sp;
    p = s + strcspn(s, sep);
    if (*p != '\0') *p++ = '\0';
    *sp = p;
    return s;
}
#endif
#endif
```