# Is there something like a wildcard character for sscanf()

Tags: c

My string may or may not have some parameters, and so I want to insert that flexibility into my sscanf.

Eg My string can be **"111|g|8|9|r|4|5"** , Where the 3rd and 4th are optional paramaters, so we can have an input like this **"111|g|||r|4|5"**

Is there something like a wildcard character like * in regex which I can use ?

eg `sscanf(mystr,"%d|%c|*|*|%c|%d|%d", &int1, &char1, &int2, &int3, &char2,&int4,&int5);`

Comment: I don't think so. The parameter list has to match the number of assignments.
Have you considered strtok()?

Comment: @BryanT `strtok` will take the whole group of delimiters. I suggest `strsep` which handles them individually.

Comment: @Weather Vane - you're correct. strtok might also have a problem with empty fields. Is strsep always available though?

Comment: @BryanT `strsep` is not in the MSVC library.

Comment: @Weather Vane  `strsep()` is not in the standard C library.

Comment: Did you find any of these answering to your question? If so, have you thought about [accepting one of the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/190417)?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.

`scanf` can only do simple conversions. If you need more complex matching, you must build a custom parser or use a richer library.

Here, the parsing can be done by hand:

- store the current position in string
- search the next `'|'` in the string with `strchr` => if not found, you have last token
- store its position + 1 as a hold position
- replace the `'|'` with a `'\0'`
- the current token is the string starting at current position
- set the current position to the hold position and iterate

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can be that selective with scanf so I suggest you use fgets and then sort the returned data.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the way you want to use it. However, there are alternatives.

As others have stated, you could use `strsep()` to separate the input. 
The following code allows any of the fields to be empty, which in essence, is a more like a format code or wildcard (explained in regex as `\d|*\|\w|*\|\d|*\|\d|*\|\w|*\|\d|*\|\d|*`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *my_string;
    my_string = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
    char *my_string_split;
    printf("Input: ");
    fgets(my_string, 256, stdin);

    char char1;
    char char2;
    int int1;
    int int2;
    int int3;
    int int4;
    int int5;

    my_string_split = strsep(&my_string, "|");
    for (int i = 0; my_string_split != NULL; i++) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            sscanf(my_string_split, "%d", &int1);
            break;
        case 1:
            sscanf(my_string_split, "%c", &char1);
            break;
        case 2:
            sscanf(my_string_split, "%d", &int2);
            break;
        case 3:
            sscanf(my_string_split, "%d", &int3);
            break;
        case 4:
            sscanf(my_string_split, "%c", &char2);
            break;
        case 5:
            sscanf(my_string_split, "%d", &int4);
            break;
        case 6:
            sscanf(my_string_split, "%d", &int5);
            break;
        }
        my_string_split =  strsep(&my_string, "|");
    }

    printf("%d|%c|%d|%d|%c|%d|%d", int1, char1, int2, int3,  char2, int4, int5);

    free(my_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Normal input

```
Input: 111|g|8|9|r|4|5
111|g|8|9|r|4|5
```

Handles input with empty fields

```
Input: 111|g|||r|4|5
111|g|0|0|r|4|5
```

Also, if your system doesn't provide `strsep()` there's another stackoverflow question which has a solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514474/6051408