# Split String in C to recognize consecutive tabs

Tags: c, strtok

I have a file that has certain fields separated by tabs. There will always be 17 tabs but there order can vary, such as..

```
75104\tDallas\t85\t34.46\t45.64
75205\tHouston\t\t37.34\t87.32
93434\t\t\t1.23\t3.32
```

When I use `strtok` in the following fashion

```
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
    tok = strtok(buf,"\t");

    while(tok != NULL) {
        printf("%s->",tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL,"\t");
    }
}
```

I get all the tokens, but double tabs `\t\t` or more are ignored. However, I need to know when a field is empty, I cannot have `strtok` ignore multiple tabs because the structure depends on 17 tabs being counted, using a placeholder if a field is empty.

I've tried dealing with the problem with an

```
if(tok == NULL || '')
```

but I don't think `strtok` recognizes a tab after a tab. What is the best way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Watch it - your `if(tok == NULL || '')` attempt looks like you are used to another language. It is technically valid C but almost certainly not what you wanted to do.

Comment: strtok() is unusable. Build a state machine and/or use strspn()/strcspn().

Answer (score 3):

You can't use strtok in your case. 
From `man strtok:`

> The  strtok()  function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more
>          nonempty tokens
>   ...
>   From the above description, it follows that a sequence of two  or  more
>          contiguous  delimiter  bytes in the parsed string is considered to be a
>          single delimiter, and that delimiter bytes at the start or end  of  the
>          string  are  ignored.  Put another way: the tokens returned by strtok()
>          are always nonempty strings.   Thus,  for  example,  given  the  string
>          "aaa;;bbb,",  successive  calls  to strtok() that specify the delimiter
>          string ";," would return the strings "aaa" and "bbb", and then  a  null
>          pointer

So you will have to find an alternative, which could either be manually writing a function that uses linear search and `strncpy`, or `sscanf` or using `strsep`, if it is available. The latter would very likely be my choice, because it was intended as replacement for strtok.

From `man strsep:`

> The  strsep()  function  was introduced as a replacement for strtok(3),
>          since the latter cannot handle empty fields.  However,  strtok(3)  con‐
>          forms to C89/C99 and hence is more portable.

Comment: And here is a simple implementation of `strsep()` that you can use if it's not already part of your toolchain: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8514474/12711

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `strsep`, which was introduced specifically to address the fact that `strtok` skips over consecutive delimiters:

```
char *cur, *nxt;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL)
{
    nxt = buf;
    while ((cur = strsep(&nxt, "\t")) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s->",cur);
    }
}
```

NOTE: the string passed to `strsep` must be writable (passing a literal string specifically does not work). It will be modified by `strsep` (delimiters are overwritten with NUL characters on consecutive calls).

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to start digesting how this could be implemented , the below function will do that , read it please. :

```
int splitLine(char *buf, char **argv, int max_args)
{
    int arg;

    /* skip over initial spaces */
    while (isspace(*buf)) buf++;

    for (arg = 0; arg < max_args
        && *buf != '\0'; arg++) {
        argv[arg] = buf;
        /* skip past letters in word */
        while (*buf != '\0'
            && !isspace(*buf)) {
            buf++;
        }
        /* if not at line's end, mark
        * word's end and continue */
        if (*buf != '\0') {
            *buf = '\0';
            buf++;
        }
        /* skip over extra spaces */
        while (isspace(*buf)) buf++;
    }
    return arg;
}
```

This function use a space separator, you can reimplement to use any other one.