# Valgrind errors on strtok() wrapper function

Tags: c, valgrind, strtok

Am trying to create a wrapper function for `strtok()` but before tokenizing the input string I would like the function to process the string as follows 
 
1. if the first character is `,` then insert a character say `N` as the first character followed by `,`
2. if two `,` characters follow each other then insert a character say `N` in between them.
3. if `,` and `;` characters follow each other then insert a character say `N` in between them.

Tried to realloc before `strncpy()`.

```
str = realloc(str, (strlen(array) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

My solution :

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100000

int
utils_to_array(char **ret, char *str, char *delim)
{
  char array[ARRAY_SIZE];

  for (int y = 0, z = 0; str[y] != '\0'; y++, z++){ /* LINE 43*/
    if ((str[y] == '\0') && (str[y + 1] == delim[0])){ /* ,*/
      array[z] = 'N';
      ++y;
      ++z;
      array[z] = ',';
    } else if ((str[y] == delim[0]) && (str[y + 1] == delim[0])) { /*,, */
      array[z] = str[y];
      z++;
      array[z] = 'N';
      y++;
      z++;
      array[z] = str[y];
    } else if ((str[y] == delim[0]) && (str[y + 1] == delim[1])) { /* ,; */
      array[z] = str[y];
      z++;
      array[z] = 'N';
      y++;
      z++;
      array[z] = str[y];

    } else {
      array[z] = str[y];
    }
  }

  str = strncpy(str, array, strlen(array)); /* LINE 71 */

  size_t n = 0;
  for (char *p = strtok(str, delim); p ; p = strtok(NULL, delim)) { /* LINE 74 */
    ret[n++] = p;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind mem test:

```
==7534== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7534==    at 0x4C2CAA8: __strlen_sse42 (vg_replace_strmem.c:462)
==7534==    by 0x400BBA: utils_to_array (fxt_utils.c:71)
==7534==    by 0x400F4A: parser_gsection_new (fxt_parser.c:115)
==7534==    by 0x40096E: main (test_parser.c:10)
==7534== 
==7534== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7534==    at 0x54DAB1E: strtok (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==7534==    by 0x400C3D: utils_to_array (fxt_utils.c:74)
==7534==    by 0x400F4A: parser_gsection_new (fxt_parser.c:115)
==7534==    by 0x40096E: main (test_parser.c:10)
==7534== 
==7534== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7534==    at 0x54DAB4E: strtok (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==7534==    by 0x400C3D: utils_to_array (fxt_utils.c:74)
==7534==    by 0x400F4A: parser_gsection_new (fxt_parser.c:115)
==7534==    by 0x40096E: main (test_parser.c:10)
==7534== 
==7534== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7534==    at 0x54DAB51: strtok (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==7534==    by 0x400C3D: utils_to_array (fxt_utils.c:74)
==7534==    by 0x400F4A: parser_gsection_new (fxt_parser.c:115)
==7534==    by 0x40096E: main (test_parser.c:10)
==7534== 
==7534== 
==7534== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7534==     in use at exit: 18,812 bytes in 7 blocks
==7534==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 0 frees, 18,812 bytes allocated
==7534== 
==7534== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7534==    definitely lost: 208 bytes in 1 blocks
==7534==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7534==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7534==    still reachable: 18,604 bytes in 6 blocks
==7534==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7534== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==7534== 
==7534== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7534== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==7534== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If I use

```
if (str[0] == ',') { /* LINE 44 */
```

I get the following valgrind error

```
> ==11195== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==11195==    at 0x400B79: utils_to_array (fxt_utils.c:43)
> ==11195==    by 0x400F1D: parser_gsection_new (fxt_parser.c:115)
> ==11195==    by 0x40096E: main (test_parser.c:10)
> ==11195== 
> ==11195== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==11195==    at 0x4C2CAA8: __strlen_sse42 (vg_replace_strmem.c:462)
> ==11195==    by 0x400B8D: utils_to_array (fxt_utils.c:72)
> ==11195==    by 0x400F1D: parser_gsection_new (fxt_parser.c:115)
> ==11195==    by 0x40096E: main (test_parser.c:10)
> ==11195== 
> ==11195== 
> ==11195== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
> ==11195==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x1FFEFFFD6A
> ==11195==    at 0x1FFEFFFD6A: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x1FFEFFFD7F: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4DFFFF: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195==    by 0x2C4E2C4E2C4E2C4D: ???
> ==11195== 
> ==11195== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==11195==     in use at exit: 18,812 bytes in 7 blocks
> ==11195==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 0 frees, 18,812 bytes allocated
> ==11195== 
> ==11195== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==11195==    definitely lost: 208 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==11195==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==11195==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==11195==    still reachable: 18,604 bytes in 6 blocks
> ==11195==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==11195== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
> ==11195== 
> ==11195== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==11195== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
> ==11195== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Example of string input:

> ,,126HC:\Users\410239\Documents\Work\Queries\Lapa Parts
>   17-08-2017\AA00001106762_Ao_REINFORCEMENT\AA00001106762_AO_REINFORCEMENT.stp,30HAA00001106762_AO_REINFORCEMENT,22HAutodesk
>   Inventor 2016,7Hunknown,32,38,7,99, 
>   15,,1.,2,2HMM,1,0.08,15H20180314.163749,0.01,10000.,4Hnone,4Hnone,11,0,
>   15H20170818.085306;

Comment: What in the world do `x`, `y`, and `z` keep track of?  Call them that.  Right now, your code is incomprehensible.

Comment: `if ((str[y] == '\0')` will never be true because it is the terminating condition of the for loop.

Comment: @AndrewHenle y for looping through str and z for array

Comment: You do too many `y++` and `z++`. You do it _in_ the loop and you do it in the `for` statement. That way you skip characters and may not detect the terminating `str[y]` being `'\0'`. Probably that is what valgrind is telling you.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie if i use `str[0] == ','` I get the second valgrind output.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I understand but how best can I do the character copying and insertion.

Comment: Also `array` is larger than `str` because it stores the new character that are not in `str` so I thought it would be ideal to loop through it fast before `str[y]=='\0'` couldn't find a better way

Comment: If your goal here is to ensure that multiple consecutive delimiters are not collapsed into a single delimiter, you should use`strsep` instead of `strtok`. `strsep` reports all fields, including zero-length ones. (But it still doesn't give you any indication as to which delimiter was used.)

Comment: @rici strsep() works perfectly but its not portable beacause it conforms to 4.4BSD standard.

Comment: [portable open source implementation of strsep](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/libkern/strsep.c)

Comment: Other implementation links in this question's answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512958/is-there-a-windows-variant-of-strsep

Comment: @rici Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `strsep()` can handle empty fields ,there was no longer any need to insert N when the field is empty. This is how i solved the problem using linux man pages and links sent by @rici :
https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/libkern/strsep.c
[Is there a windows variant of strsep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512958/is-there-a-windows-variant-of-strsep)

```
int
utils_to_array(char **ret, char *str, char *delim)
{
  size_t count = 0;
  char *tok;

  while((tok = strsep(&str, delim)) && count < PARAM_MAX)
        ret[count++] = tok;

  return 0;
}
```