# What's the difference between strtok_r and strtok_s in C?

Tags: c, windows, linux, compiler-errors, strtok

I'm trying to use this function in a C program that needs to be able to compile in Linux and Windows. At first I tried using strtok_r, but then when I compiled on windows, it complained about the function not existing and said it would assume it's an extern function, but then failed. I then used strtok_s and it compiled! Then I tried on Linux but now it's complaining that there is an "undefined reference to 'strtok_s'".

Is one a windows only function and the other a linux function??? What can I do to make it compile on both?

Comment: [`strtok_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html) is POSIX; [`strtok_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) is Windows. Use plain `strtok()` which is available in all implementations *(supporting C89)*.

Comment: The problem is I need to strtok a string while strtok-ing another string, which is why I need this one since it saves state.

Comment: @pmg - unless you need thread or buffer overrun safety

Comment: Well ... then I refer to [R..'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9021604/25324).

Comment: @MartinBeckett Wait what? Where does it save the state? There are only two arguments, one is NULL (on the second token), the other is what character you want to find. I want to be able to strtok a string, find something in that string and strtok that one, then go back to the original string and continue to strtok it.

Comment: @pmg - sorry was thinking of something else, my mistake!

Comment: @user390608: The problem you're encountering is exactly why `strtok` is such a horrible interface. It is *stateful* and *non-reentrant*.

Comment: This is an ancient question by now, but I felt the need to point out that strtok_s is C11, not just Windows.

Comment: @kyrias close - it's C11 Annex K, which Ulrich Drepper has fought tooth-and-nail to keep from libc users. No, really, that's why linux devs can't use it. One guy.

Comment: on linux / unix, in glibc, there is [strsep](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html#index-strsep). see also [What are the differences between strtok and strsep in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218625/what-are-the-differences-between-strtok-and-strsep-in-c)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of these functions are really ugly, unintuitive idioms for parsing strings, and usually fail to meet your particular application's requirements in subtle ways. Even moreso for the plain `strtok` in standard C. Just throw them out and write your own code to iterate over the `char` array and break it up as needed. `strchr`, `strspn`, and `strcspn` can be helpful in doing this or you can just work from scratch on the array.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why these functions are bad? It seems more intuitive to me than going through character by character and searching for things.

Comment: (1) the separator char is overwritten/lost, so unless you only have one possible separator, you're losing information. (2) multiple consecutive separators are treated as one, which makes sense if your separator is whitespace but not if it's a comma, for instance..

Comment: Please note that surely in *some* situations, the `strtok` semantics are just what you want and the only issue is the statefulness (which `strtok_r` and `strtok_s` fix). I just find that every time I tried to use them, there's at least one aspect of my parsing needs they don't support, and it ends up being easier to just write the code directly.

Comment: -1: For parsing a string that's been read into a temporary buffer, where you want to throw away the delimeters and you only want the strings valid until you're done parsing, strtok is precisely what you want and strtok_r/strtok_s is much better as it is reentrant.

Comment: "write your own code" -- see also [How do I split a string without strtok?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335514/how-do-i-split-a-string-without-strtok/40341255#40341255) and [String separator, similar to strtok](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173723/string-separator-similar-to-strtok) and [glibc/string/strtok_r.c](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/string/strtok_r.c)

Answer (score 43):

`strtok_s` is simply the Windows version of `strtok_r` which is standard everywhere else.

One (common I would think) way to make a program portable when it comes to functions like `strtok_s`/`strtok_r` is to use the preprocessor:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
/* We are on Windows */
# define strtok_r strtok_s
#endif
```

As the prototypes and functionality is the same, you can now use only `strtok_r`.

Comment: This would probably break if compiling on cygwin which reports itself as windows but has posix interfaces like `strtok_r` already defined. Using something like `#ifndef HAVE_STRTOK_R` (and detecting it in the build scripts) would be better.

Comment: @R..: cygwin does not in fact define `_WIN32` (or `_WIN64`) for precisely this reason -- its commonly used to identify code that is non-unix like.  Cygwin defines `__CYGWIN__` and `__unix__` instead

Comment: It may be good to know that there is an other `strtok_s` in C11 with a completely different signature: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

Comment: @ChrisDodd There are still problems on MinGW. MinGW predefines `_WIN32` but it supports `strtok_r`.

I think it is better to check the `_MSC_VER` macro.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on other answers, so I'll have to provide my own.

1) To address this statement:

> "strtok_s is a buffer overrun safe version of strtok on Windows. The
>   standard strtok on windows is thread safe..."

This is not true. strtok_s is the thread safe version for the MSVC compiler. strtok is not thread safe!

2) To address this statement:

> "This would probably break if compiling on Cygwin which reports itself
>   as windows but has POSIX interfaces like `strtok_r` already defined."

Again, not true. The difference is which compiler you use. When using Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler, MSVC, the function is `strtok_s.` Another compiler, such as the GNU Compiler Collection, GCC, may use a different standard library implementation such as `strtok_r`. Think compiler, not target platform, when identifying which function to use.

In my opinion, Joachim Pileborg's answer is the best one on this page. However, it needs a small edit:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) /* || defined(_WIN64) */
#define strtok_r strtok_s
#endif
```

Both _WIN32 and _WIN64 are predefined macros provided by the MSVC compiler. _WIN64 is defined when compiling a 64 bit target. _WIN32 is defined for both 32 and 64 bit targets. This is a compromise that Microsoft made for backwards compatibility. _WIN32 was created to specify the Win32 API. Now you should consider _WIN32 to specify Windows API -- it is not specific to a 32 bit target.

Comment: You are wrong about the first point: strtok **is** thread-safe on Windows, since two distinct threads can safely use that function within the same process, even if strtok have other problems as explained in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16821026/656988) by @JameyKirby.

Comment: MinGW predefines `_WIN32` but it supports `strtok_r`, so it is better to check the `_MSC_VER` macro.

Answer (score 7):

Just to clarify. `strtok` is thread safe in Windows. `strtok` uses a `TLS` variable to maintain the last pointer for each thread. However, you can not use `strtok` to interleave access to more than one token string per thread. `strtok_r` and `strtok_s` both address this interleaving problem by allowing the user to maintain the context via the third parameter. Hope this helps.

Comment: Although not helpful for the OP, who is looking for a portable solution, this was very helpful for me to find out why my legacy code crashes on Linux but not on Windows. As I thought I knew how strtok behaves, I didn't care to read the Windows strtok documentation thoroughly...

Answer (score 5):

strtok_r is a thread safe version of strtok on POSIX systems

[strtok_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a buffer overrun safe version of strtok on Windows. The standard strtok on windows is thread safe, so strtok_s should be.

Comment: `strtok_r` is part of POSIX and has been for years (decades?)

Comment: I still think the answer isn't terribly useful since it just covers what OP (mostly) already knew, not how to solve the problem.

Comment: @R - the solution is you can use strok_r on Posix and strtok_s on Windows, Joachim's solution describes how. OR you can program windows using only the Posix subsystem

Comment: @MartinBeckett it's C11 Annex K standard, not just Windows :)

Comment: @AlexanderRiccio    Microsoft `strtok_s` and C11 `strtok_s` are completely different!
Microsoft `strtok_s` has only 3 parameters, while C11 `strtok_s` has 4 parameters.

The prototype of Microsoft `strtok_s` is `char* strtok_s(char* str, const char* delimiters, char** context);` while the prototype of C11 `strtok_s` is `char *strtok_s(char *restrict str, rsize_t *restrict strmax, const char *restrict delim, char **restrict ptr);`.

Answer (score 1):

MinGW also predefines `_WIN32` but it supports `strtok_r`, so I don't think it is a good idea to check the `_WIN32` macro. It is better to check the `_MSC_VER` macro, which is the macro for Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define strtok_r strtok_s
#endif
```

WARNING: Microsoft `strtok_s` and C11 `strtok_s` are completely different! Microsoft `strtok_s` has only 3 parameters, while C11 `strtok_s` has 4 parameters, so it can be a compatible issue in the future.

The prototype of Microsoft `strtok_s` is

```
char* strtok_s(char* str, const char* delimiters, char** context);
```

The prototype of C11 `strtok_s` is

```
char *strtok_s(char *restrict str, rsize_t *restrict strmax, const char *restrict delim, char **restrict ptr);
```