# How to split string by commas optionally followed by spaces without regex?

Tags: c, parsing

I need this simple split

```
Item one, Item2,  Item no. 3,Item 4
>
Item one
Item2
Item no.3
Item 4
```

- I know I can use `%*[, ]` format in [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) to ignore comma and spaces, but this is not accurate: the separator should be exactly one comma optionally followed by spaces.
- I think I can't use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) either, since space alone is not a delimiter.

Do I really need regex here, or is there any effective short way to encode this?

Comment: Use `strtok` to find the next comma, then scan forward until you find a non-space character ?

Comment: Good idea, could be an answer

Comment: Or alternatively, you can just write a very simple for loop to do this. Takes 5 minutes of your time and it will be far more efficient than any library calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

```
char inputStr[] = "Item one, Item2,  Item no. 3,Item 4";
char* buffer;

buffer = strtok (inputStr, ",");

while (buffer) {
    printf ("%s\n", buffer);          // process token
    buffer = strtok (NULL, ",");
    while (buffer && *buffer == '\040')
        buffer++;
}
```

Output:

```
Item one
Item2
Item no. 3
Item 4
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use `strtok_r` instead of `strtok` to avoid funny bugs in multithreaded environments.

Comment: `strtok_r` isn't standard C, is it? I don't know whether it would compile on a Windows machine, for example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021502/whats-the-difference-between-strtok-r-and-strtok-s-in-c

Comment: what does the `while (buffer && *buffer == '\040')` line do?

Comment: `while (buffer)` checks that the character in the buffer is not NUL, i.e., that we are not at the end of the string. `(*buffer == '\040')` checks that the character in the buffer is a space. So as long we are not at the end of the string, AND the current character is a space, we move to the next char.

Answer (score 0):

You can step through the string looking for , or 0x00 and replace any , with a 0x00 then step past any spaces to find the start of the next string.  Regex is a lot easier.