# How to split nested deliminated strings in c?

Tags: c, strtok, split, csv

I was wondering, how am i able to split that kind of strings.

For example i have the following string: "80,8080,27001-27010,90"

I first want to split at the comma but if there is a minus in that substring i want to split it and get the difference between the two numbers by converting them via atoi().
The string i want to split is a list of ports, and i want to generate an array of integer with all ports enumerated.
The strtok-function seems not suitable for this problem, is there any easy solution for this?

Using of strtok_r
Example:

```
 substr1 = strtok_r(portlist, delim1, &saveptr1);
 while(substr1 != NULL){
    substr2 = strtok_r(substr1, delim2, &saveptr2);
    substr1 = strtok_r(NULL, delim2, &saveptr1);
 }
```

Comment: `strtok-function seems not suitable`... please let us know why?

Comment: strtok saves the preparsed strings if i use strtok again for splitting the substring 27001-27010 i will loose the progress i previously made so i will not be able to parse the port 90.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, you can use `strchr` to find the point where to split a token, thereby avoiding losing the progress.

Another way is to use `strtok_r`, which is a reentrant version of `strtok` that doesn't have any internal state.

**Edit:**

`strtok_r` is not part of standard C. It is part of POSIX.1-2001.
I think most major compilers support it. In Windows, the corresponding function is called `strtok_s`. 
A good way to make this portable is

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
/* We are on Windows */
# define strtok_r strtok_s
#endif
```

As described in Joachim Pileborgs answer to 
[What's the difference between strtok_r and strtok_s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021502/whats-the-difference-between-strtok-r-and-strtok-s-in-c)

Comment: So i have to create two save-pointers. One when i want to save the main progress and one to save the progress of the substring is that correct?

I posted the example in the original question

Comment: Yes. You need a second loop to get all (both) values from the `strtok_r` on `delim2`.  Also, the last strtok_r should use `delim1`.

Comment: Thanks you saved my day, i got really rusty in c programming

Answer (score 0):

I prefer sscanf to parse strings in C

```
char *text =  "80,8080,,,27001-27010,+tt90";
int p[10];
int offset = 0, i = 0;
char bufDel[32], bufDigit[16];
while (sscanf(text+offset, "%[0-9]%[^0-9]", bufDigit, bufDel) != EOF) {
    offset += strlen(bufDigit) + strlen(bufDel);
    sscanf(bufDigit, "%d", &p[i]);
    ++i;
    bufDigit[0] = '\0';
    bufDel[0] = '\0';
}
```

%*[^0-9] reads all characters except digits 0-9 and throws them away.
The output is
80 8080 27001 27010 90

Comment: Problem is i need a dynamic solution that portlist can differ, the range can also be on another position so this would not work.

Comment: That is good and well if you have a fixed format. In this case I think the string is just an example and that the number of `,` and `-` is variable.

Comment: But thank you for sharing this, in fact that i am not able to use strtok_r for my programm, because of the given compiler config i have to parse my substring in a different way.

Comment: I assume you want to read integers from a string and the delimiers are non digits. The exact number of integers is unknown. Of course this is possible with sscanf, see edited program