# Understanding strtok_s

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, console-application

It's been ages I've worked with C++, so please bear with me.

I'm a C# developer, but this C++ console app broke, and I'm managing it now. I'm currently debugging it with VS2010.

Due to confidentiality and the sheer amount of code, I cannot post all the code.

The console essentially reads and parses a 6MB XML file. Everything used to work, until yesterday, where I receive a "Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc" with the following line of code:

```
strtok_s(0, "=", &token);
```

When I place the cursor over "&token", I see the error "token = 0xcccccccc ".

I wanted to clarify a few things:

```
strtok_s(buf, "=", &token);
strtok_s(0, "=", &token);
strtok_s(0, "=", &token);
```

what is the *0* doing as parameter? I assume that in the first *strtok_s*, *token* will point to the first instance of the char '=' in *buf*. But in the 2nd instruction, what's the purpose of '0'? Is it looking for '=' inside *token*?

Obviously, something has changed in the XML. So, finally, considering that this is parsing a 6MB file  (w/ 870K lines of text) and the C++ function that reads the XML is 700+ lines long, what's the best way to debug this? And no, slitting my wrists is not being condidered... yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `strtok_s`?  It doesn't work with `std::string` (which is what you want to be using to hold your strings), and it can't be used on string literals.  Just parse normally using string iterators.

Comment: It's dangerous to never check whether the return value is NULL.

Comment: note that `strtok_s` is windows only. see also [What are the differences between strtok and strsep in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218625/what-are-the-differences-between-strtok-and-strsep-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing 0 as the first argument (NULL is more readable perhaps) means "find the next token in the string".  Seeing 0xcccccccc as the value of the last argument ("token" is the wrong name) tells you that the string was never searched for the *first* token.  In other words, a call to `strtok_s(buf, "=". &token)` was never made.  Or the "token" value wasn't preserved from an earlier call to strtok_s().  So it no longer knows what string needs to be searched.  Kaboom.

In either case it is a hard bug in the code that isn't affected by the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

first af all i would DIFF a "broken" XML code and a working one. I THINK you'll find the broken one has less = where expected.

0, or bette NULL as first parameter, will simply re-use token

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) which explains the use of `strtok_s` with the help of examples.

The first parameter can be NULL when you have invoked `strtok_s` at the least once, and the third parameter already contains a pointer to the last found token. In such a case, the next call to `strtok_s` can take it up from where the last call found the token.

Specifically, in your case, an access violation usually indicates a buffer overflow or garbage in the pointer. Something happened to `token` variable, which has caused its value to become `0xcccccccc`. You need to point out the code where `token` takes on this value and find what's causing the overrun.