# C - strtok_s - Access violation reading location

Tags: c

I can't understand why I get the following message for my function below (in Visual Studio 2015).

> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000002C.

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915010/understanding-strtok-s) but it does not help me.

What this code is about. 
There is a string of ints separated in groups of "index,value" pairs. Indexes are unique. Each group is separated by a semi-colon. Example: 1,2;3,5;2,2;3,4
I am trying to get an array of int with each value at its index.

My code so far extracts the strings and puts it into a `char* buffer`.
Then I separate the groups of "index,value" by the semi-colons and store them in `char** arrayKeyValue`, which is a member of `struct inputElement` . The other struc member is a int representing the number of "index,value" groups in the array. I do this with the function "separateStringBySemicolon".

Then I try to separate each group of "index,value" into a new array, where at each "index" will match its "value". I do this by passing my struct to the function "separateKeyValue". I use `strtok_s` but I get an error.

The first call to the function below (`token2 = strtok_s(arrayOfKeyValue[j], sepComma, &next_token2);`) brings the error. I understand that `token2` or `next_token2` cannot be accessed, but I am not sure. And if so, why?

```
double* separateKeyValue(struct inputElement* inputElement)
{
    int count = inputElement->length;
    char** arrayOfKeyValue = inputElement->data;

    double* arrayDecimal = malloc(count * sizeof(double));
    char sepComma = ','; //wrong should be char sepComma[] = ",";
    char* token2 = NULL;
    char* next_token2;

    printf("Value in arrayofkeyvalue: %s", arrayOfKeyValue[0]);

    for (size_t j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        token2 = strtok_s(arrayOfKeyValue[j], sepComma, &next_token2);
        unsigned int index;
        sscanf_s(token2, "%d", &index);

        double value;
        sscanf_s(next_token2, "%d", &value);

        arrayDecimal[index] = value;

        printf("res[%d] = %d\n", index, arrayDecimal[index]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return arrayDecimal;
}
```

Comment: This question is missing a lot of context. What input exactly is passed to function `separateKeyValue`?

Comment: What is `inputElement`? What is `inputElement->data`? How are they initialized? How and from where do you call this function? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Specifically, the problem is almost certainly with one of the values of `arrayofKeyValue[j]`, and that's almost the only thing you haven't shown us.

Comment: By the way, you have lots of pointers in your code, but you never check if any of them are `NULL`. You're also using `printf` to print a `double` value value as it was an `int`, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I added more explanations and details.

Comment: Here's your problem: `char sepComma = ',';`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That was it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying a `char` constant, `sepComma`, as the second parameter to `strtok_s`, where it [expects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) a string of delimiter characters.

(not so) Coincidentally, the ASCII value of `','` is 0x2C.