# What are the implications and usage guidelines for strsep's obseletion of strtok?

Tags: c, portability, strtok, manpage, strsep

The (BSD) man pages for `strtok` state in the first line under description

> This interface is obsoleted by `strsep(3)`.

Does that mean that `strtok` should on the whole not be used? It does not provide any usage guidelines about `strtok`'s being obsolete beyond that. On `strsep`'s man page, it states under history

> The `strsep()` function is intended as a replacement for the `strtok()` function.  While the `strtok()` function should be preferred for portability reasons (it conforms to ISO/IEC 9899:1990 (``ISO C90'')) it is unable to handle empty fields, i.e., detect fields delimited by two adjacent delimiter characters, or to be used for more than a single string at a time.

So, my questions are this

1. Should `strsep` on the whole be used over `strtok`?
2. How much of a portability issue is there with `strsep` as it appeared in BSD4.4 which was in June of 1994?
3. Do all POSIX compliant machines have `strsep`?

Comment: Do you want your code to be portable? Then you should keep using `strtok`. It is, after all, part of the C standard which `strsep` isn't. As an example, `strsep` doesn't exist on Windows using the Visual Studio run-time.

Comment: `strsep` is not a part of POSIX, so there may be a POSIX compliant OS out there that does not have `strsep`.

Comment: I'm actually going to close this question. I just found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7219504/5021321). Sorry!

Comment: "The man pages for strtok state in the first line under description
This interface is obsoleted by strsep(3)." -- **What** manual pages? The one I'm looking at, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html, doesn't say that. In any case, it's not true. Use strtok_r, not strsep or strtok.

Comment: @JimBalter [BSD Man Pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strtok&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)

Comment: In the future, please provide such links in your question ... it makes a world of difference. That BSD says that something is "obsoleted" is irrelevant outside of BSD.

Comment: @JimBalter I did not know that it said otherwise outside of the BSD man pages until you mentioned it, but I will do so in the future.

Comment: Well sure, you didn't know, that's why you're asking questions. :-) Again, that's why it's important to be specific and not just say "the" -- there is rarely a "the", there are numerous.

Comment: In general, if the 'multiple separator' problem isn't a problem, you should use `strtok_s()` on Windows (technically, it's also a part of the Annex K Safer Functions in C11 — ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — but usually not available on Unix) and `strtok_r()` on Unix (POSIX).  These are call compatible and take a pointer to extra space which fixes the reentrancy problem.  If you need to detect empty fields between adjacent delimiter characters, the `strtok()` functions are not the correct functions to be using.  If you don't need to detect empty fields, then `strsep()` is the wrong function to be using.

Comment: See also [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions)