# Split a string based on contiguous delimiters

Tags: c

I'm looking to split a sting based on a specific sequence of characters but only if they are in order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  char **split;
  char *tmp;

  split = malloc(20 * sizeof(char *));
  tmp  = malloc(20 * 12 * sizeof(char));
  for(i=0;i<20;i++)
  {
    split[i] = &tmp[12*i];
  }

  char *line;
  line = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));

  strcpy(line, "Test - Number -> <10.0>");
  printf("%s\n", line);
  i = 0;

  while( (split[i] = strsep(&line, " ->")) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s\n", split[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

This will print out:

```
Test 
Number
<10.0
```

However I just want to split around the -> so it could give the output:

```
Test - Number
<10.0>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between strtok and strsep in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218625/what-are-the-differences-between-strtok-and-strsep-in-c)

Comment: Please show the input.

Comment: You can use `strstr` to find a substring and use it for calculating the splits.

Comment: @WeatherVane His input is currently hardcoded: `strcpy(line, "Test - Number -> <10.0>");`

Comment: Both `strtok` and `strtok` interpret their delimiter string as "any of these characters may delimit", so neither of those functions will come close to doing what you want.

Comment: @Pablo I deleted a similar comment because the input might be `"<11.0>"` and not `"<10.0>"`. That only works on the hard coded input and fixed expectation.

Comment: strstr looks promising I'll play around with that.

Comment: You can find the first `'<'` with `strchr` and then extract the value with `sscanf` which will stop at the `'>'`. Alternatively, you don't have to use the same delimiter set with `strtok` and `strsep` each time. You can use `"<"` the first time and `">"` the second time (and restructure the loop).

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you've completely misunderstood his question.

Comment: @WeatherVane I still think `strstr` is the best way to do that, by replicating what `strtok_r` does but using `strstr` instead if `strchr` (for every char of the delim).

Comment: @stackptr I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. The OP's is just using the wrong function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do the splits with an ordered sequence of delimeters is
to replicate `strtok_r` behaviour using `strstr`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *substrtok_r(char *str, const char *substrdelim, char **saveptr)
{
    char *haystack;

    if(str)
        haystack = str;
    else
        haystack = *saveptr;

    char *found = strstr(haystack, substrdelim);

    if(found == NULL)
    {
        *saveptr = haystack + strlen(haystack);
        return *haystack ? haystack : NULL;
    }

    *found = 0;
    *saveptr = found + strlen(substrdelim);

    return haystack;
}


int main(void)
{
    char line[] = "a -> b -> c -> d; Test - Number -> <10.0> ->No->split->here";

    char *input = line;
    char *token;
    char *save;

    while(token = substrtok_r(input, " ->", &save))
    {
        input = NULL;
        printf("token: '%s'\n", token);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This behaves like `strtok_r` but only splits when the substring is found. The
output of this is:

```
$ ./a 
token: 'a'
token: ' b'
token: ' c'
token: ' d; Test - Number'
token: ' <10.0>'
token: 'No->split->here'
```

And like `strtok` and `strtok_r`, it requires that the source string is
modifiable, as it writes the `'\0'`-terminating byte for creating and returning
the tokens.

---

**EDIT**

> Hi, would you mind explaining why `'*found = 0'` means the return value is only the string in-between delimiters. I don't really understand what is going on here or why it works. Thanks

The first thing you've got to understand is how strings work in C. A string is
just a sequence of bytes (characters) that ends with the `'\0'`-terminating
byte. I wrote bytes and characters in parenthesis, because a character in C is
just a 1-byte value (on most systems a byte is 8 bit long) and the integer
values representing the characters are those defined in the [ASSCI](http://www.asciitable.com/) code
table, which are 7-bit long values. As you can see from the table the
value 97 represents the character `'a'`, 98 represents `'b'`, etc. Writing

```
char x = 'a';
```

is the same as doing

```
char x = 97;
```

The value 0 is an special value for strings, it is called `NUL` (null character)
or `'\0'`-terminating byte. This value is used to tell the functions where a
string ends. A function like `strlen` that returns the length of a string, does
it by counting how many bytes it encounters **until** it encounters a byte with
the value 0.

That's why strings are stored using `char` arrays, because a pointer to an array
gives to the start of the memory block where the sequence of `char`s is stored.

Let's look at this:

```
char string[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0, 48, 49, 50, 0 };
```

The memory layout for this array would be

```
0     1     2     3     4     5    6     7     8     9
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+----+
| 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o' | \0 | '0' | '1' | '2' | \0 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+----+
```

or to be more precise with the integer values

```
0    1     2     3     4     5   6    7     8   9   10
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+----+----+----+---+
| 72 | 101 | 108 | 108 | 111 | 0 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 0 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+----+----+----+---+
```

Note that the value 0 represents `'\0'`, 48 represents `'0'`, 49 represents
`'1'` and 50 represents `'2'`. If you do

```
printf("%lu\n", strlen(string));
```

the output will be 5. `strlen` will find the value 0 at the 5th position and
stop counting, however `string` stores two strings, because from the 6th
position on, a new sequence of characters starts that also terminates with 0, thus making it a
second valid string in the array. To access it, you would need to have pointer
that points past the first 0 value.

```
printf("1. %s\n", string);
printf("2. %s\n", string + strlen(string) + 1);
```

The output would be

```
Hello
012
```

This property is used in functions like `strtok` (and mine above) to return you
a substring from a larger string, without the need of creating a copy (that would be
creating a new array, dynamically allocating memory, using `strcpy` to create
the copy).

Assume you have this string:

```
char line[] = "This is a sentence;This is another one";
```

Here you have one string only, because the `'\0'`-terminating byte comes after
the last `'e'` in the string. If I however do:

```
line[18] = 0;  // same as line[18] = '\0';
```

then I created two strings in the same array:

```
"This is a sentence\0This is another one"
```

because I replaced the semicolon `';'` with `'\0'`, thus creating a new string
from position 0 to 18 and a second one from position 19 to 38. If I do now

```
printf("string: %s\n", line);
```

the output will be

```
string: This is a sentence
```

Now let's us take look at the function itself:

```
char *substrtok_r(char *str, const char *substrdelim, char **saveptr);
```

The first argument is the source string, the second argument is the delimiters
strings and the third one is doule pointer of `char`. You have to pass a pointer
to a pointer of `char`. This will be used to remember where the function should
resume scanning next, more on that later.

This is the algorithm:

```
if str is not NULL:
    start a new scan sequence from str
otherwise
    resume scanning from string pointed to by *saveptr

found position of substring_d pointed to by 'substrdelim'

if no such substring_d is found
    if the current character of the scanned text is \0
        no more substrings to return --> return NULL
    otherwise
        return the scanned text and set *saveptr to
        point to the \0 character of the scanned text,
        so that the next iteration ends the scanning
        by returning NULL

otherwise (a substring_d was found)

    create a new substring_a until the found one
    by setting the first character of the found
    substring_d to 0.

    update *saveptr to the start of the found substring_d
    plus it's previous length so that *saveptr
    points to the past the delimiter sequence found in substring_d.

    return new created substring_a
```

This first part is easy to understand:

```
if(str)
    haystack = str;
else
    haystack = *saveptr;
```

Here if `str` is not `NULL`, you want to start a new scan sequence. That's why
in `main` the `input` pointer is set to point to the start of the string saved
in `line`. Every other iteration **must** be called with `str == NULL`, that's
why the first thing is done in the `while` loop is to set `input = NULL;` so
that `substrtok_r` resumes scanning using `*saveptr`. This is the standard
behaviour of [`strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).

The next step is to look for a delimiting substring:

```
char *found = strstr(haystack, substrdelim);
```

The next part handles the case where no delimiting substring is
found<sup>2</sup>:

```
if(found == NULL)
{
    *saveptr = haystack + strlen(haystack);
    return *haystack ? haystack : NULL;
}
```

`*saveptr` is updated to point past the whole source, so that it points to the
`'\0'`-terminating byte. The return line can be rewritten as

```
if(*haystack == '\0')
    return NULL
else
    return haystack;
```

which says if the source already is an empy string<sup>1</sup>, then return
`NULL`. This means no more substring are found, end calling the function. This
is also standard behaviour of [`strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).

The last part

```
*found = 0;
*saveptr = found + strlen(substrdelim);

return haystack;
```

is handles the case when a delimiting substring is found. Here

```
*found = 0;
```

is basically doing

```
found[0] = '\0';
```

which creates substrings as explained above. To make it clear once again, before

Before

```
*found = 0;
*saveptr = found + strlen(substrdelim);

return haystack;
```

the memory looks like this:

```
       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
       | 'a' | ' ' | '-' | '>' | ' ' | 'b' | ...
       +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
       ^     ^
       |     |
haystack     found
*saveptr
```

After

```
*found = 0;
*saveptr = found + strlen(substrdelim);
```

the memory looks like this:

```
       +-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
       | 'a' | '\0' | '-' | '>' | ' ' | 'b' | ...
       +-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
       ^     ^                  ^
       |     |                  |
haystack     found              *saveptr
                                because strlen(substrdelim)
                                is 3
```

Remember if I do `printf("%s\n", haystack);` at this point, because the `'-'` in
found has been set to 0, it will print `a`. `*found = 0` created two strings out
of one like exaplained above. [`strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) (and my function which is based on
`strtok`) uses the same technique. So when the function does

```
return haystack;
```

the first string in `token` will be the token before the split. Eventually
`substrtok_r` returns `NULL` and the loop exists, because `substrtok_r` returns
`NULL` when no more split can be created, just like [`strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).

---

**Fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>An empty string is a string where the first character is already the
`'\0'`-terminating byte.

<sup>2</sup>This is very important part. Most of the standard functions in the C
library like `strstr` will **not** return you a new string in memory, will
**not** create a copy and return a copy (unless the documentation says so). The
will return you a pointer pointing to the original plus an offset.

On success `strstr` will return you a pointer to the start of the substring,
this pointer will be at an offset to the source.

```
const char *txt = "abcdef";
char *p = strstr(txt, "cd");
```

Here `strstr` will return a pointer to the start of the substring `"cd"` in
`"abcdef"`. To get the offset you do `p - txt` which returns how many bytes
there are appart

```
b = base address where txt is pointing to

b     b+1   b+2   b+3   b+4   b+5   b+6
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
^           ^
|           |
txt         p
```

So `txt` points to address `b`, `p` points to address `b+2`. That's why you get
the offset by doing `p-txt` which would be `(b+2) - b => 2`. So `p` points to
the original address plus the offset of 2 bytes. Because of this bahaviour
things like `*found = 0;` work in the first place.

Note that doing things like `txt + 2` will return you a new pointer pointing to
the where `txt` points plus the offset of 2. This is called pointer arithmetic.
It's like regualr arithmetic but here the compiler takes the size of an object
into consideration. `char` is a type that is defined to have the size of 1,
hence `sizeof(char)` returns 1. But let's say you have an array of integers:

```
int arr[] = { 7, 2, 1, 5 };
```

On my system an `int` has size of 4, so an `int` object needs 4 bytes in memory.
This array looks like this in memory:

```
b = base address where arr is stored

address       base        base + 4    base + 8    base + 12
in bytes      +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
              |    7      |    2      |    1      |    5      |
              +-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
pointer       arr         arr + 1     arr + 2     arr + 3
arithmetic
```

Here `arr + 1` returns you a pointer pointing to where `arr` is stored plus an
offset of 4 bytes.

Comment: I see, looking for `" ->"` but this leaves unwanted spaces in the tokens, would `" -> "` be better? Has OP defined the input well enough?

Comment: @WeatherVane I wanted my function to behave like `strtok`. If you leave spaces between the delims `a : b : c`  and you do `strtok(..., ':')` then your tokens are going to `a `, ` b `, ` c`. I wanted to emulate that behaviour.

Comment: Hi, would you mind explaining why  '*found = 0' means the return value is only the string in-between delimiters. I don't really understand what is going on here or why it works. Thanks

Comment: @JohnMeighan I've updated my answer addressing your last question

Comment: @Pablo Thank you that really explains it in detail.