# strtok not splitting a string properly?

Tags: c, fread, strtok

**Summary**

I wrote some code which takes in a file with line separated words. This file contains every word in the dictionary, and is over 100000 lines long. I needed to do this so I could enter each word in a hash table and do a bunch of stuff, but that isn't important to my question. So the way I did this was reading the file using `fopen`, `fread`, etc, (the string which holds the files txt I will refer to as filetxt) and then splitting the filetxt string by `\n` characters using `strtok` to get each individual word. Problem is, `strtok` is splitting filetxt only once into two separate strings, as shown in a snippet of my output below. Why isn't it splitting every line?

**Code**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int hash(const char *word) {
    // Find the place the first letter of {word} has in the alphabet (0 based)
    int pos = toupper(word[0]) % 32 - 1;
    return pos;
}

int main(void) {
    // Opening dictionary and writing the contents to a string
    FILE *file = fopen("dictionaries/large", "r");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    int len = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    char *filetxt = malloc(len + 1);
    fread(filetxt, len, 1, file);
   
    // Splitting every line
    char *token = strtok(filetxt, "\n");
    // declaring i for debugging purposes, seeing how many times the string is split
    int i = 0;
    while (token) {
        printf("%s", token);
        printf(" %i\n", i);
        token = strtok(NULL, "");
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Output Snippet**

```
a 0
aaa
aaas
aachen
aalborg
aalesund
aardvark
aardvark's
... (I left out the irrelevant 900000 lines of code)
zulu
zulu's
zulus
zurich
zurich's
zwilich
zwitterion
zwitterionic
zwitterions
zygote
zygote's
zygotes
zymurgy
 1
```

**Dictionary File Snippet**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/raX1V.jpg
Please tell me if more of my dictionary is necessary.

Comment: Why not use `fgets()` in a loop?

Comment: @Barmar True, I will probably do that instead, but I am still curious why this problem is occuring.

Comment: `strtok(NULL, "");` should be `strtok(NULL, "\n");`

Comment: Also, you need to add a null byte at the end of `filetxt`.

Comment: @Barmar Alright thanks.

Comment: @Barmar so fread len+1 instead of len?

Comment: No, `filetxt[len]=0;`

Comment: And please stop using `strtok()`. It is beyond repair.

Comment: @wildplasser What do you mean?

Comment: I think they're recommending you use `strsep()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218625/what-are-the-differences-between-strtok-and-strsep-in-c