# How can I resolve 'cimport' errors in Cython?

Tags: python, cython

In a .pyx Cython file, I am trying to import several C functions as below:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport atof

from libc.string cimport strlen, strsep
```

I get an error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strsep

I have been trying to web search and understand what is going on here, but I can't figure it out. Is *strsep* available?

Comment: See this answer specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7219504/4657412 - `strsep` is non-standard and probably not available on Windows, so you just can't use it on Windows